# How to make small tournament lobbies with PUN in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm investigating to see if this is possible in PUN. We want to make small 8 people tournaments where they play 1v1 games against eachother.

My basic idea was to create a lobby for each tournament and then have them join rooms to play against each other and then go back to the lobby to set up the next match. Would this work? I'm not sure if there's a better solution.

Also if this is the right approach, is there a way to get the people in the lobby? Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is one issue in your approach: Other than a `Room` a `Lobby` in photon has no host / master client and also no own properties => Who will be responsible for initializing and driving the tournament ? As long as you are not in a room you can't tell other players which room(s) they should join etc. I would actually rather have all players tht belong to the tournament in one `Room` and from there let the master client "run" the tournament by assigning two players to play against each other (however this will look like) and just ignore other players in the same room. See it more like "Tables"

Comment: I mean for sure there are ways to go around that .. you could e.g. have 8 players join a lobby (the first one becomes the tournament master) and at the same time they all join a certain room on Photon-Chat (of course automated) and commincate the room assignements and winners etc via Photon-Chat .. invisble to the actual users .. but this is for sure not trivial ;) But this way you could make certain control communication across multiple rooms .. could also kick players immediately if a lobby is already "full" etc so actually they could first connect to chat and request the join to the lobby